# How to implement ClaimsRetriever interface in wso2Is

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I need to override the default behavior of DefaultClaimsRetriever, in order to do so I am implementing the ClaimsRetriever interface.
Unfortunately when overriding the ClaimsRetriever, the new class wont compile since compiler can not resolve the IdentityException class.
Those are the dependencies I defined:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.utils</artifactId>
        <version>${org.wso2.carbon.utils.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.identity</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth</artifactId>
    <version>${org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>slf4j.wso2</artifactId>
            <groupId>slf4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.xerces</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.xerces</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>resolver</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.xerces</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>serializer</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.xerces</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.user.core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.wso2.carbon.user.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework</artifactId>
        <version>${org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.logging</artifactId>
        <version>${org.wso2.carbon.logging.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

which dependency am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.